# MsDeploySourceManifest - RunCommand: Set options (DontUseCommandExe, waitInterval)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msdeploy, webdeploy

I can't seem to set the runCommand options in my MSDeploySourceManifestTask.  Path works fine but the others do not.

```
  <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="runCommand">
    <waitInterval>5000</waitInterval>
    <Path>dir</Path>
    <dontUseCommandExe>True</dontUseCommandExe>
  </MsDeploySourceManifest>
```

Whats the deal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specifically declare the provider settings you want to add in an extra metadata item `<AdditionalProviderSettings/>` (semi-colon separated). Change your item to this and it'll work fine:

```
<MsDeploySourceManifest Include="runCommand">
  <Path>dir</Path>
  <waitInterval>5000</waitInterval>
  <dontUseCommandExe>True</dontUseCommandExe>
  <AdditionalProviderSettings>waitInterval;dontUseCommandExe</AdditionalProviderSettings>
</MsDeploySourceManifest>
```

Comment: I've set it in my manifest thanks to this answer, but the `waitInterval` value seems to be ignored.  Have you seen this problem?  *Edit:*  It seems that if you don't super-clean your obj dir and rerun the build that simply running `msbuild /t:Package` will give you stale values.  The values don't seem to be ignored once I do this.